# Is there a resolution handling library for love2d on windows

Tags: love2d

Push.lua is great resolution handling library but some of its functions are limited in windows. 
Especially when it comes to changing color.
And that is what I am having the problem with.
Whenever I give a specific color, it shows white.

Could anyone please tell me if there is any other resolution handling library for love2d on windows or if there is anyway I can get push.lua to work with changing some of its code.

Comment: Welcome to SO Dulantha Wijesooriya. Unfortunately a question asking for a library or tool recommendation are not suitable for SO so I'm flagging to close. You'd be better off asking this question on a forum or subreddit.

Answer (score 1):

RGB values must be a decimal number between 0 and 1 in the current version of love2d. By calling `love.graphics.color(127, 45, 22)` this will actually default to `love.graphics.color(1,1,1)` (which is the colour white) because 1 is the maximum value for R, G and B. If you want the RGB values of 127, 45 and 22 you should enter `love.graphics.color(127/255, 45/255, 22/255)` which is equivalent to `love.graphics.color(0.498, 0.176, 0.086)`